# DOM Element Re-Positioning

Tags: javascript, html

**Objective:**
Want to move an element from one place to another in DOM.

**Condition:**
I can easily do this using jQuery but i am working in an environment where jQuery is not available and adding it is not an option for such a small task ~ so i need a vanila js solution.

**Example:**

Make this:

```
<div class="elem-1">Element 1</div>
<div class="elem-2">Element 2</div>
```

Into this (on page load):

```
<div class="elem-1">
    Element 1
    <div class="elem-2">Element 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.appendChild()` will work just fine. Did you try?

Comment: ok, fine ~ i guess i should remove the question...

Comment: You can't delete now as it got upvoted answer, just remember in the future to try yourself before asking, then sharing what you tried if you're still unable to achieve your goal.

Comment: hmmmm..., ok thanks for the tip :) ~ i have used jQuery so much that i was out of clue where to start in vanila JS.

Comment: OK, fair enough and for what it's worth I didn't downvote. Also, if you can't use jQuery here why using the tag?

Comment: Cuz pro jQuery guys will know how to convert it to vanila JS ~ i was about to share jQuery method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append it where you want it.

```
document.querySelector('.elem-1').appendChild(
    document.querySelector('.elem-2')
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Quentin. But i need to do this with classes not id.
~ give a moment i will do that my self.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList (which is array-like), not a single Element. Note the plural in the function name.

Comment: hmm.. i see.. Again Thanks Quentin.